# when I use word2vec::word2vec function I repeatedly get out of session in R server

Tags: r, word2vec

I have installed this package and tried to use `word2vec` on my R server.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mukul13/rword2vec")
model=word2vec(train_file = "text8",output_file = "vec.bin",binary=1)
```

But I repeatedly get

> Error: 'session is aborted'.

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Or what I could use instead of `word2vec`?

Also you can get 'text8' in https://github.com/mukul13/rword2vec  <- here

Comment: Hmm, a quick check of the commands you ran causes no similar error on my system. What version of R are you running? Is R running locally? (If not there make be limits w.r.t access to compilers that devtools needs)...

Comment: My r version is 3.5.1 and I'm running locally.  When I run a common example of word2vec code like this. "model=word2vec(train_file = "text8",output_file = "vec.bin",binary=1)" I get session aborted .

Comment: Just in case: once you have installed rword2vec you don't need to rerun the first two lines, just use a `library(rword2vec)` to load it. Testing this out I had issues when I did not have the text8 test file (available here: http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip, needs unzipping). Further tests from the github page failed for me and the repo has not been updated for years, you may want to try another R wrapper such as https://github.com/bmschmidt/wordVectors if you can't get it working from there.

Comment: @Gavin Thaks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just find the reason that we have to have a real train_file to the model, i.e. the file has to be at the right directory and it cannot just be null or anything else.